# Android FAB drag and drop

Tags: android, button, drag, floating-action-button

I need a FloatingActionButton (FAB) in my Activity that you can drag around. But you also can click on it. From another post I copied this:

```
fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                float startX;
                int lastAction;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            startX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                            lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            view.setX(event.getRawX() + startX);
                            lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                               edit();
                            }
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:

                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

The problem is: If you want to click on it often it does not recognize it as a click but as a move. so this is not very precise. How can I change the code to make it better?

Answer (score 1):

check the dragged distance, if its less than 10px => the user probably didn't want to drag.

```
 fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            float startX;
            float startRawX;
            float distanceX;
            int lastAction;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        startX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        startRawX = event.getRawX();
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        view.setX(event.getRawX() + startX);

                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        distanceX = event.getRawX()-startRawX;
                        if (Math.abs(distanceX)< 10){
                          edit();
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```